# How to give flags and env variables in k3s Airgap installation

Tags: bash, rancher, k3s, rancher-rke

I am trying to convert my [k3s script installation](https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/installation/install-options/#options-for-installation-with-script) via `curl -sfL`

```
curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | K3S_KUBECONFIG_MODE="644" INSTALL_K3S_EXEC="--flannel-backend=none --cluster-cidr="$cluster_cidr" --disable=traefik" sh -
```

to [Airgap installation](https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/installation/airgap/#install-options) with command:
`INSTALL_K3S_SKIP_DOWNLOAD=true /usr/local/bin/install.sh` in shell script.

I want to pass same flags and env var `K3S_KUBECONFIG_MODE="644" INSTALL_K3S_EXEC="--flannel-backend=none --cluster-cidr="$cluster_cidr" --disable=traefik" sh -` in `INSTALL_K3S_SKIP_DOWNLOAD` installation the same way as I am giving in top most curl command ?

The top most curl command is working, but after replacing curl with SKIP_DOWNLOAD its failing.

**PS:** This is failing to set the flags and variables:

```
INSTALL_K3S_SKIP_DOWNLOAD=true /usr/local/bin/install.sh | K3S_KUBECONFIG_MODE="644" INSTALL_K3S_EXEC="--flannel-backend=none --cluster-cidr="$cluster_cidr" --disable=traefik" sh -
```

can someone help me here ?

Answer (score 0):

There was a recent fix in k3s, which may be what you were seeing: https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s/issues/9570

I'd recommend using the latest version and trying again, as your install command looks correct to me.

One more point, I would recommend referring to [k3s docs](https://docs.k3s.io/installation/airgap#installing-k3s-in-an-air-gapped-environment) directly instead of through Rancher. In this case I think you were fine, but sometimes Rancher docs get out of sync with other docs like K3s.